# invoke $ajax on confirmation

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

how can i prevent/invoke $ajax by pressing Cancel or Ok button by calling  myConfirm function ? currently i get undefined if i try with:

```
 var vCal = myConfirm('dialogText', 'dialogTitle');
```

do i missed something ?

```
function myConfirm(dialogText, dialogTitle) {
$('<div style="padding: 10px; max-width: 500px; word-wrap: break-word;">' + dialogText + '</div>').dialog({
    .....
    buttons: {
      "OK" : function (e) {
        console.log('yes');
        $(this).dialog('destroy');
        return true;
      },
      "Abbrechen" : function (e) {
        console.log('no');
        $(this).dialog('destroy');
        return false;
      }
    }
});
}   

function openTickerDialogDelete (id) {
....

if(!myConfirm('dialogText', 'dialogTitle')) {
    return false;
} 
console.log('call ajax');
$.ajax({    
    .....
        success: function( data ) {

        }
})
}
```

using return confirm() works great, but i would like to use the dialog box

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply place the ajax call inside the OK button function it will execute when the button is clicked:

```
function myConfirm(dialogText, dialogTitle, okCallback) {
$('<div style="padding: 10px; max-width: 500px; word-wrap: break-word;">' + dialogText + '</div>').dialog({
    .....
    buttons: {
      "OK" : function (e) {
        if ($.isFunction(okCallback)) {
           okCallback();
        }
        $(this).dialog('destroy');
        return true;
      },
      "Abbrechen" : function (e) {
        console.log('no');
        $(this).dialog('destroy');
        return false;
      }
    }
});
}
```

Open dialog with any success function:

```
myConfirm('dialogText', 'dialogTitle', function(){
    $.ajax({    
        .....
        success: function( data ) {

        }
    });
});
```

Open a dialog without a success function

```
myConfirm('dialogText', 'dialogTitle');
```

Calling a function with parameters:

```
myConfirm('dialogText', 'dialogTitle', function(){
    tickerDelete(id);
});
```

Comment: i had that before, but in that case i need to add "myConfirm"  multiple times for each ajax confirmation..... i would like to choose it in other $.ajax too

Comment: ok so you just want to be able to open dialogs with or without the ajax call when it's "ok"?

Comment: if dialog returns true, go on with the ajax call, should be able to implement in each $.ajax if confirmation needed

Comment: I updated the answer, added a callback so you can implement any function you want that will run when the user clicks ok.

Comment: myConfirm('dialogText', 'dialogTitle', tickerDelete (id));

fires ajax within tickerDelete() without waiting for button yes/no

Comment: try `myConfirm('dialogText', 'dialogTitle', tickerDelete);`

Comment: but i need to pass ID, without ID it waits till i press OK/cancel